# ORA-06550: Wrong number or type of arguments error | Calling Oracle Procedure with Table type IN parameter

Tags: c#, oracle11g

We have one stored procedure in Oracle which accepts 1 IN parameter of type Table of `Varchar2(50)`.

This is just sample Procedure to test how to pass IN parameter of type table. We are using `PLSQLAssociativeArray` type parameter to pass the array as IN parameter.

But it is throwing error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
arguments in call to 'SPGETMARKETPROMOTIONS' 
ORA-06550: line 1, column > 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I have read mostly all the threads related to `"ORA-06550: Wrong number or type of arguments error"` but those were of no help.

Below are code snippets of Procedure and c# code used to call Procedure.

**SP:**

```
TAB_VAR_ARRAY TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spGetMarketPromotions(promoid IN TAB_VAR_ARRAY) 
   IS
   BEGIN
    Update MKT set MKT_NM='UnitedKings' where MKT_CD='UK';
    END;
/
```

**C# Code to Call this SP:**

```
public static int test(List<string> pid)
        {
           // create and open connection object
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(dbConnectionString);
            con.Open();

            // insert the new jobs into the jobs table
            // create command object and set attributes
            OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "spGetMarketPromotions";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //cmd.ArrayBindCount = 2;
            cmd.BindByName = true;

            // create parameter objects for each parameter
            OracleParameter prid = new OracleParameter("promoid",               OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
            string[] list = { "sdafsad", "sdaf" };
            prid.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            prid.Value = list;
            prid.Size = list.Length;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(prid);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return 1;
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Type TAB_VAR_ARRAY TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) and Procedure are not defined inside package. Can this be a problem?

Comment: Found the solution: Custom TYPE Tables should be declared within the package scope to be used with PLSQLAssociativeArray, these should not be declared at the Schema level.